# WCF REST service - called twice

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a small RESTfull service that returns images ( like this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/) ).

My config looks like :

```
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and

```
<services>
<service name="namespace.ServiceName">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="namespace.IServiceName">
</endpoint>
</service>
</services>
```

and

```
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="web">
    <webHttp/>

</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

**The Problem**

For some reason when calling it from different browsers i get different behaviours:

1. ie - every thing works fine
2. chrome - my service gets called twice -
   once for the image and once when the browser looks for for the Favicon
3. Firefox - my service gets called twice - both times the browser requests the image (i.e. the url in the address bar)

has anyone seen this before ? is this a binding issue ? how do i resolve it ?

thanks alot :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats normal, almost every Browser looks for a favicon, try to ignore it. If your Service will be public also remember that speiders will request for robots.txt